# No input clusters found in, Check your -c argument error in clustering

Tags: mahout

1.seqdirectory

> mahout seqdirectory --input /user/hdfs/input/new1.csv --output
>   /user/hdfs/new1/seqdirectory --tempDir
>   /user/hdfs/new1/seqdirectory/tempDir

2.seq2sparse

> mahout seq2sparse --input /user/hdfs/new1/seqdirectory --output
>   /user/hdfs/new1/seq2sparse -wt tfidf

3.kmeans

> mahout kmeans --input /user/hdfs/new1/seq2sparse/tfidf-vectors
>   --output /user/hdfs/new1/kmeans -c /user/hdfs/new1/clusters/kmeans -x 3 -k 3 --tempDir /user/hdfs/new1/kmeans/tempDir

and then error is occured

```
Failing Oozie Launcher, Main class [org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver], main() threw exception, No input clusters found in /user/oozie/mahout/new1/clusters/part-randomSeed. Check your -c argument.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No input clusters found in /user/oozie/mahout/new1/clusters/part-randomSeed. Check your -c argument.
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.buildClusters(KMeansDriver.java:217)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run(KMeansDriver.java:148)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run(KMeansDriver.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.main(KMeansDriver.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMapper.map(LauncherMapper.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

Oozie Launcher failed, finishing Hadoop job gracefully


Oozie Launcher ends
```

Why kmeans driver can't make clusters in Hadoop with oozie system?
In hadoop with not oozie system, it worked.

Affects Version/s: MAHOUT 0.7, 0.8-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

With -c /user/hdfs/new1/clusters/kmeans option, 
we require to make sure the clusters available.

This can help https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/K-Means+Clustering
Please check for the c option.

Comment: The link you posted is no longer available. Can you repost the solution?